# Calling a WSE web-service though a proxy

Tags: web-services, proxy, wse

I'm using Web Services Enhancements 3.0 to call a web-service from an ASP.NET application written in C# with Visual Studio 2005.

I can call the web-service in Internet Explorer if I change the network connection settings to use a specific SOCKS5 proxy but from the .ASPX page I get an error message that tells me that I should be using the proxy.

Do you know how to configure the web-service client to use the proxy?

Thanks

PS:

Adding the following to Web.config doesn't work:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://theproxy:8080" bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "enabled" attribute of defaultProxy element to "true" to make it work:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy **enabled="true"**>
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://theproxy:8080" bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This should work.